# Mysql - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

This is my the code of my query :

```
$payments = DB::table('payments')
                    ->join('invoices', 'invoices.id', '=', 'payments_invoices.invoice_id')
                    ->join('payments_invoices', 'payments.id', '=', 'payments.payment_id')
                    ->leftJoin('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'payments.client_id')
                    ->leftJoin('contacts', 'contacts.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
                    ->where('payments.account_id', '=', Auth::user()->account_id)
                    ->where('payments.is_deleted', '=', false)
                    ->where('invoices.is_deleted', '=', false)
                    ->where('clients.is_deleted', '=', false)
                    ->where('contacts.deleted_at', '=', null);
```

when I try to show the result of this query it gives me :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'payments_invoices.invoice_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `payments`.`payment_date`, `payments`.`amount`, `invoices`.`public_id`, `invoices`.`invoice_number`, `clients`.`name` as `client_name`, `contacts`.`email`, `contacts`.`first_name`, `contacts`.`last_name`, `clients`.`currency_id`, `clients`.`public_id` as `client_public_id`, `clients`.`user_id` as `client_user_id` from `payments` inner join `invoices` on `invoices`.`id` = `payments_invoices`.`invoice_id` inner join `payments_invoices` on `payments`.`id` = `payments`.`payment_id` left join `clients` on `clients`.`id` = `payments`.`client_id` left join `contacts` on `contacts`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id` where `payments`.`account_id` = 1 and `payments`.`is_deleted` = 0 and `invoices`.`is_deleted` = 0 and `clients`.`is_deleted` = 0 and `contacts`.`deleted_at` is null and `contacts`.`is_primary` = 1 order by `payments`.`payment_date` desc limit 50)
```

knowing that this query works correctly :

```
$query = DB::table('payments')
                    ->join('accounts', 'accounts.id', '=', 'payments.account_id')
                    ->join('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'payments.client_id')
                    ->join('invoices', 'invoices.id', '=', 'payments_invoices.invoice_id')
                    ->join('payments_invoices', 'payments.id', '=', 'payments.payment_id')                     
                    })
                    ->leftJoin('payment_types', 'payment_types.id', '=', 'payments.payment_type_id')
                    ->where('clients.is_deleted', '=', false)
                    ->where('payments.is_deleted', '=', false)
                    ->where('invitations.deleted_at', '=', null)
                    ->where('invoices.deleted_at', '=', null)
                    ->where('invitations.contact_id', '=', $contactId)
                    );
```

what should I do please ??

Comment: Include your table definition

Comment: payments('id','account_id','client_id','amount','user_id','payment_date')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
   ->join('payments_invoices', 'payments.id', '=', 'payments.payment_id')
```

Does not make sense.You try join another table using a field from the table itself.So probably you want to join on `payments_invoices.payment_id`

Then you can try change the order in which you join the tables

```
$payments = DB::table('payments')
                    ->join('payments_invoices', 'payments.id', '=', 'payments_invoices.payment_id')
                    ->join('invoices', 'invoices.id', '=', 'payments_invoices.invoice_id')

                    ->leftJoin('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'payments.client_id')
                    ->leftJoin('contacts', 'contacts.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
                    ->where('payments.account_id', '=', Auth::user()->account_id)
                    ->where('payments.is_deleted', '=', false)
                    ->where('invoices.is_deleted', '=', false)
                    ->where('clients.is_deleted', '=', false)
                    ->where('contacts.deleted_at', '=', null);
```

Comment: still doesn't work `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'payments.payment_id`

Comment: Happy I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Base from your query:

```
$payments = DB::table('payments')
                    ->join('invoices', 'invoices.id', '=', 'payments_invoices.invoice_id')
                    ->join('payments_invoices', 'payments.id', '=', 'payments.payment_id')
```

You are joining `payments` table to `invoices` table. And your on clause looks like: `ON invoices.id = payments_invoices.invoice_id`

But `payments_invoices` table was joined only on the next line.

Just correct the relation between `payments` and `invoices` table (if there is), then it's good.

Since `payments` and `invoices` is many-to-many: try this:

```
DB::table('payments')
                ->join('payments_invoices', 'payments.id', '=', 'payments_invoices.payment_id')
                ->join('invoices', 'invoices.id', '=', 'payments_invoices.invoice_id')
```

In case you have `payments_id` column on `payments_invoices` table.

Comment: but OP is using the same payment.payment_id in her working query

Comment: `payments_invoices` table is a join table which is joined on `invoices` and `payments` tables both

Comment: Join must come first. `payments_invoices.invoice_id` was used but `payments_invoices` wasn't joined yet

Comment: @Lara what's the relationship between `payments` and `invoices` table? If there is none, then you should join `payments_invoices` first.